# Azure Learning Path

Tags: c#, azure

I have about a year and half experience in C# (win forms, XNA, WP7) and I want to take my education to the next level.

I have an idea I want to make for the WP7 that uses Azure but I have very little knowledge in web based programming.

My question is, what would be a good learning path so I can get up to learning Azure? I have tried jumping right into Windows Azure but had a very difficult time understanding most of it and was jumping around researching various aspects of what I was originally trying to learn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:**
Wasn't satisfied with my old answer, so I'd just suggest downloading the [Azure Training Kit](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8396) and practicing because experience is the best teacher.

Get yourself a  copy of [Windows Azure Platform](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430235632) too, it will give you a good general understanding of how Azure works and expose all the gotchas and limitations.

If you want to test your code in a real environment (you should, because it works differently locally) then you should sign-up for the free 3 month Azure trial.

Answer (score 0):

This will help you in the right way

```
Windows Azure
Operating system as a service

Microsoft SQL Azure
Fully relational database in the cloud

Windows Azure platform AppFabric
Easy to connect cloud and on-premises applications
```

http://msmvps.com/blogs/abu/archive/2010/01/06/learning-windows-azure-complete-tutorial-cum-getting-started-windows-azure-platform-training-kit-december-update.aspx